# Excluding, Including xPath

Tags: xpath

I am trying to exclude and include following xpaths in the existing xpath, not quite sure how I can do it

```
//exclude  -> //*[@id="ires"]/ol/li[6]/div/a[1]/img
//include -> //*[@id="ires"]/ol/li[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/h3/a/@href
```

add to below xpath

```
$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//*[@id="ires"]/ol/li['.$k.']/h3/a/@href');
```

Comment: Can you please show an example of DOM and what you are wanting to get.

Comment: with $nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//*[@id="ires"]/ol/li['.$k.']/h3/a/@href');  I am getting proper results, just dont know how to exclude and include other xpaths, if I could use classes there is no problem but I cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can surely include result by using pipe:

```
//*[@id="ires"]/ol/li['.$k.']/h3/a/@href | //*[@id="ires"]/ol/li[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/h3/a/@href
```

I can't understand how what you're trying to exclude ends up in your results in the first place.